# Why Gimbal Beacon takes time to Scan or Advertise?

Tags: android, bluetooth, beacon, gimbal

Currently , i am experimenting on Gimbal Beacons on Android. I have integrated Gimbal SDK to my Android Studio. So , i testing the beacon with Gimbal SDK samples but i observed most of the time Gimbal Beacon takes minimum 5-10 minutes  or more to get discovered by the Android device. Sometimes i have to reboot the Android device and re-install the applications to do the discovery.

So , i am trying to understand , is it because of the Beacon Hardware or i need to make some change in the code?

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Are these detection times when the app is in the foreground or background?

Comment: no it don't have certain detection times , it's quite random. user can't be sure when it will get detected. : (